# (R)Discovery dataset from faraway package: How can you make predictions with both dependent and independent variables? Poission Regression

Tags: r, statistics, regression, predict, poisson

##Here I used the 'discoveries' dataset from the faraway package.

```
library('faraway')
data("discoveries")
```

#made a variable 'year' from 1860 to 1959

```
year = 1860:1959
```

#here I fit a poisson regression model with discoveries as dependent and year as independent.

```
fit_pois =  glm(discoveries ~ year, data = discoveries, family = poisson)
```

##The question is, what is the probability that there are 4 discoveries in year '1960'(assuming model is right and is predicting the future). I tried to do this with

```
pred_pr = predict.glm(fit_pois, data.frame(discoveries = 4, year = 1960, type = 'response'))
```

##However when I predict on the data, it gives out numbers that are not probabilities. Plz Help!!

Comment: There's no error, from the documentation, `type` *"the alternative "response" is on the scale of the response variable. "* Predicted probabilities only apply to binomial models.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by replicating your model:

```r
library('faraway')
data("discoveries")

year = 1860:1959
fit_pois <- glm(discoveries ~ year, data = discoveries, family = poisson)
```

Now if we use `predict`, our `fit_pois` model will tell us the predicted rate of discoveries for any given year(s). It will completely ignore any `discoveries` in the data frame passed to the `newdata` parameter of `predict`, because our model predicts discoveries based solely on the `year` variable.

Note also that in your example you have included `type = "response"` as a variable in the `newdata` data frame, rather than passing it as a parameter to `predict`. So the prediction line should look like this:

```r
pred_pr = predict.glm(fit_pois, newdata = data.frame(year = 1960), type = 'response')
```

And the result we get is:

```r
pred_pr
#>        1 
#> 2.336768
```

Let's think what this means. Since we are doing a Poisson regression, this number represents the expected value of `discoveries` in the year 1960. This means that we can estimate the probability of there being exactly 4 discoveries if we examine the Poisson distribution with an expected value (also known as a *lambda*) of 2.336768. Let's use `dpois` to see the probabilities of getting 0 to 6 discoveries if the lambda is 2.336768:

```r
plot(0:6, dpois(0:6, pred_pr), type = "h")
```

[image]

So the probability of there being exactly 4 discoveries in 1960 is:

```r
dpois(4, pred_pr)
#> [1] 0.1200621
```

i.e. almost exactly 12%